# How to compare one employee to all employees salary in django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
emp = Employee.objects.filter(id=1)

Persons =  Employee.objects.extra(select={'difference':(emp.values_list("Salary",flat=True)[0]-float('Salary'))})
```

But it give Error :

> Exception Type:   ValueError
>
> Exception Value:could not convert string to float: 'Salary'.

How can i solve this Error.

Comment: Hardly sufficient information. Post your models

Answer (score 0):

`'Salary'` is indeed a string, and not a number. So python cannot make that conversion. You don't want the string `'Salary'`, you want the field `Salary`. To do that, you need to use [Django F() expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions).

Or here, in the context of `.extra(select...`, I believe Django is just expecting an SQL string. For example: `.extra(select={'diff': "%f - salary"}, select_params=emp.Salary)`

But as the [docs for extra explain](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra), you might really want to use [.annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate) combined with [F() expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions). `.extra` is set for deprecation.

Comment: It give error "TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable"